# Code clears page instead of going to new site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to create this chrome extension that you enter an address and click a button and it goes there. This may sound like a stupid idea but somehow a server block on a site is bypassed by chrome extensions. This is my current code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Website Opener</title>
   <style type="text/css">
    body 
    {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande";
      height: 100%;
    }
   </style>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#url').change(function() {
        var newurl = $('#url').val();
        $('a.target').attr('href', newurl);
      });
      });
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id='url' value='http://'>
      <br>
      <p><a class="target" href="">Go!</a></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

What it currently does is just make the page blank or clear the input box instead of going to the new site.

I have tried javascript .open() method, this is trying jQuery. I'm mainly wondering if there are any other ways to do this or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Mouse over the link before clicking it. The target URL should appear in the status bar at the bottom of your window.

Comment: Have you tried window.location.href = newurl; ?

Comment: As I can see, you did not attach jQuery script to your page.

Comment: Ok, I just tried that, it just shows the current page url, not the one I want it to go to.

Comment: Is there a way to do that easily while keeping it in the html code, @kuzzmi ?

Comment: You can't have javascript code in an html file for a Chrome extension. You need to put it in a separate file and include it via a `<script>` tag. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will help you:

1. Place jQuery to your `<head>` or in the end of your page, but before your code.

   ```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Then rewrite your code to use a `keypress` event:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#url').keypress(function() {
           $('.target').attr('href', this.value)
       })
   });
   ```

FYI: `change` event will happen when you changed a value of your input and set the focus out of it. So if you type an url and place your mouse cursor on the link and press it, `change` event will trigger AFTER your click. So be careful with those events.

**UPDATE**:
I just saw that you're doing an extension for GC. 
The best practices tell us to divide application by layers' aim. HTML and JS should be separated.

In your `manifest.json` you have to add

```
"js": ["jquery.js", "content_script.js"]
```

and move your JavaScript logic from HTML file to the content_script.js.

Comment: Tried that, it still shows the url of the page I'm on.

Comment: Please, try one more time with those things I placed to the update section